# Vim: how do I determine the status of a process within a terminal tab?

Tags: vim

The `:ls` command in Vim output the current buffers in Vim. If one of the buffers is a terminal, there are some useful flags to examine there. For example, if the command was:

```
term echo "test"
```

`:ls` will contain this as one of the entries:

```
...
  7 %aF  "!echo "test" [finished]"      line 1
...
```

Is there a vim function that could return such extended information about a buffer? `:help terminal` suggests that if `modifiable` option is `off`, the job had to have finished.

> before changes can be made to a terminal buffer, the 'modifiable' option must
>   be set.  This is only possible when the job has finished:

To rephrase my question, how do I know the status of a shell process started with the `term` command?

Comment: So what's the question then? How to get an output of Ex command or how to check if terminal buffer is running a process? Please, reformulate your question.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The question is this: what logic does Vim use to determine if a a terminal process has finished **and** can I arrive at the same result by using vimscript functions. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Put yet another way, how do I get the `F` buffer indicator by using a vimscript function?

Comment: `what logic does Vim use to determine if a a terminal process has finished` Obviously, it's an ordinary child process, so Vim can manage it using underlying OS API. If you need more info consult Vim source code, otherwise your question does not make sense: just take it granted that it can; the "how" is an implementation detail.

Comment: `can I arrive at the same result by using vimscript functions` Yes, you can. `how do I get the F buffer indicator` You can do even that, but I don't see any sense in parsing "letter F", when you can simply get the process status directly. But, please, note that you should **rewrite your question's body** to get an answer, and not to put your new question inside comments. That's not how SO supposed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal process is always bound to a buffer, not a tab. In Vim there exists a function `term_getstatus()`; in Neovim it's `jobwait()`.

Here is a generic function from my config:

```
function! term#running(buf)
    return getbufvar(a:buf, '&buftype') !=# 'terminal' ? 0 :
        \ has('terminal') ? term_getstatus(a:buf) =~# 'running' :
        \ has('nvim') ? jobwait([getbufvar(a:buf, '&channel')], 0)[0] == -1 :
        \ 0
endfunction
```

Comment: Great, I just made use of this API. Thank you!